# Having trouble breaking the while loop in a program to automatically place rectangles

Tags: python, while-loop

so first of all thank you for your attention, i´m having a problem with a program because a need it to automatically place rectangles in an area, and i´ve tried to do a brute force aproach, but i can´t seem to be able to break the first while loop, can you please help me?

The second while loop i can break, the first is the one i´m having trouble with, so here it is a bit of my code, a think it can help:

```
    for rect in self.figures_not_placed:
            f=self.figures_not_placed[rect]     
            px=1
            py=1
            L=self.heigt
            A=self.width
            while( 0<px<L):
                if self.__valid_place(f,px,py)==False:
                    px=px+1
                else:
                    while(0<py<A):
                        if self.__valid_place(f,px,py)==False:
                            py=py+1                            
                        elif self.__valid_place(f,px,py)==True:
                            f.setposx(px)
                            f.setposy(py)
                            self.figures_placed[rect] = f 
                            del self.figures_not_placed[rect]
                            break
```

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: you want two breaks in-a-row?

Comment: There is so much missing from your code that it is difficult for us to answer. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What's the condition to break the outter loop? There's no break anywhere that would do that in your code.

Comment: i will add more to the code then, thank you two by the way

Comment: @RoryDaulton i´ve added more code, maybe it helps

Comment: @PhilipFeldmann i want to break the outter loop when i find a place to place the rectangle, meaning, right after i break the inner loop

Comment: @Arman maybe, i´ve tried two in a row and it didn´t work, i wanted to break the outter loop so the" for rect in self.figures_not_placed" could continue

Comment: On this site, show your appreciation by upvoting all the useful answers. You do that by clicking the up-arrow at the top-left of the answer. In addition, accept the best answer (if it actually answers your question) by clicking the checkmark near the top-left of the answer. That is better than saying thanks in a comment. It also helps others to see that your question was answered.

Answer (score 0):

this is a way to break out of nested loops (works just the same with `while` loops and can be nested deeper):

```
for x in range(10):
    for y in range(10):
        print(x*y)
        if x*y > 50:
            break
    else:
        continue  # executed if the loop ended normally (no break)
    break  # executed if 'continue' was skipped (break)
```

i am sure you can adapt this to your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, i will try to adapt it. Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the second break outside the inner loop, that's why 2 breaks simply don't work, one has to be in the outter loop. Like this:

```
for rect in self.figures_not_placed:
            f=self.figures_not_placed[rect]     
            px=1
            py=1
            L=self.heigt
            A=self.width
            while( 0<px<L):
                if self.__valid_place(f,px,py)==False:
                    px=px+1
                else:
                    while(0<py<A):
                        if self.__valid_place(f,px,py)==False:
                            py=py+1                            
                        elif self.__valid_place(f,px,py)==True:
                            f.setposx(px)
                            f.setposy(py)
                            self.figures_placed[rect] = f 
                            del self.figures_not_placed[rect]
                            break
                    break
```

Comment: What if `elif` inside the inner loop is never executed? You will break the outer loop in this case once the inner one is completed successfully, which is not what OP needs.

Comment: I think the correct way to do it is to write a function with a return statement instead of a break statement. There is a 'deep break problem', but there is no 'deep return problem'. In any case, the first if after the first while looks suspicious because it uses py while being out of the py loop.

Answer (score 0):

With `while` loops, you can achieve that like below:

```
break_outer_loop = False

while( 0<px<L):
    if self.__valid_place(f,px,py)==False:
        px=px+1
    else:
        while(0<py<A):
            if self.__valid_place(f,px,py)==False:
                py=py+1                            
            elif self.__valid_place(f,px,py)==True:
                f.setposx(px)
                f.setposy(py)
                self.figures_placed[rect] = f 
                del self.figures_not_placed[rect]
                break_outer_loop = True
                break
        if break_outer_loop:
            break
```